# How to write test class for Default Account Team Members?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I am writing a test class which needs to cover code related to default account Team members.
UserAccountTeamMember doesnt allow DML operation.

Can you please let me know how to solve this issue in test class?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume there no way at this moment to write test class involving Default Account team members.

Comment: Hi Is their any solution yet, about how to cover the code related to default account team member.??